# Repeat same procedure on dual if without function

Tags: php, function, if-statement

How can I repeat the same procedure in two situations without a function?

```
if(isset($x)){
  $sql = $link->query(SELECT ... WHERE param = '$x' ...);

  if($sql){
     //do procedure 1
  }else{
     //do procedure 2
}else{
  //do procedure 2
}
```

As you can see procedure 2 is called two times.
How to write it one time without a function (the function had to have to much vars)?

Comment: Why can't you use a function?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would not want to use a function, but you just need to restructure your code

```
if(isset($x) && ($sql = $link->query(SELECT ... WHERE param = '$x' ...))){
    //procedure 1
}
else{
    //procedure 2
}
```